# If I connect 10 3mm or 5mm blue LEDs to 3 AA battery power source, do I really need resistors?

Tags: led

Looks like this is a good forum to ask this basic question. I would like to connect 10 LEDS 3mm blue lights together and the power source is 3 AA batteries. Do I really need a resistor?

Comment: How are you going to connect them? Series or parallel?

Comment: It would be wise to limit starting current as 3mm Blue may rise to 3.6 but at 4.5 the current will cause excessive current and junction temps.  Thus (4.5-3.3typ)/ 15mA*10=8 Ohms. Otherwise thermal runaway may start burning out LEDs with {4.5-3.0}/20ohm(est.)=75mA going to the hottest and brightest mismatched LED with the lowest Vf.

Comment: @ Long ..not sure how i am going to connect them yet, which one do you recommend.

Comment: You cannot run in series. And parallel needs R's. Otherwise thermal runaway may start burning out LEDs with {4.5-3.0}/20ohm(est.)=75mA going to the hottest and brightest mismatched LED with the lowest Vf. If you are lucky and they are all perfectly matched then If=(4.5-3.3typ)/20 Ohms *10 LEDs=60mA per LED on fresh cells rated for only 20mA

Comment: @ Tony... I was thinking the more diodes connected will eliminate the use of a resistor.

Comment: If you know how to compute the choice of diode for internal R go ahead. possibly a 1N4148  Do the math or have an adventure..

Comment: @ Tony, Sorry for the dumb questions as I am new to using diodes and Ohm laws.  I was trying to avoid using the math lol.  One person said to put a resistor on each diode when connecting in parallel.  What do you think?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist...there were videos on youtube that tell you how to connect but they really dont go in depth on what type of diodes to get.  They simply show how they wired it together to a 3 AA battery switch and none of them looks like they used a resistor, so thats why I am so confused.

Comment: depends, search my answers for LEDs in parallel. and "diode ESR"  You need to be educated

Comment: a matched voltage like Li-Ion would be better 3.7 to 3.3V with 0.4V drop /150mA

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, I agree, i need some education on LEDs lol

Comment: LED internal resistance, Ri or ESR, like all diodes Ri=k/Pmax above threshold voltage. so a 50mW LED is 20 Ohms roughly +/-50% for all brands combined in 3mm ( est.) k=1 nominal and reduces to 0.5 for high efficacy LEDs

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist.  Thank you for taking the time to explain to a noob.

Comment: @Victor H Check out [Transistor's LED database](http://lednique.com/) for tons and tons of beginner explanations.  FYI the challenge in using LEDs without resistors is to prevent thermal runaway.  As LEDs get hotter, their resistance decreases.  If they are not cooled adequately for the power level you run them at, they draw more current and heat up more until they burn out.  As a result, you have to cool them adequately or use current control (resistors are basically the simplest and least efficient form of current control.

Answer (score 1):

AA batteries are a bad choice for powering LEDs due to the 0.8V cutoff voltage.  As the battery discharges from 1.5V to 0.8V the current changes significantly.

[image]

You should never connect LEDs to a battery without a resistor or a current limiting device like a constant current regulator (CCR).  LEDs have a forward voltage which will be different from the battery voltage.  Without another device (resistor or CCR) the LED will be forced to operate at the battery voltage rather than its V<sub>f</sub>.

When using AA batteries and resistor you must look at how the resistor value works for both 1.5V and 0.8V.

So 3 AA in series
@ 1.5V = 4.5V
@ 0.8V = 2.4V

You should connect all 10 separately each with its own resistor.

You could try all 10 wired in series but there is more likely to be an LED that cannot tolerate the stress.   I will connect 3 LEDs in series if their V<sub>f</sub> are fairly close i.e. binned LEDs.

Blue and green LEDs have the highest V<sub>f</sub> of all LEDs. Typically with a 2.9 to 3.3 V<sub>f</sub>.

I would recommend a very bright blue LED like [Cree C503B-BAS-CY0C0461](http://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/1300-C503B-BAS-BAN-GAS-GAN.pdf) with an intensity of 19,380 mcd.

You need the actual V<sub>f</sub> when selecting the resistor(s).  The published values will differ too much and using AA batteries does not leave much wiggle room.

Using 3.2V of the Cree LED:

At 4.5V the 1% resistor needed for 20 mA is 66.5Ω.
At 3.4V the minimum this LED will work properly the resistor would be 10Ω for 20 mA,

You need to use the 66.5Ωbefcause if you use the 10Ω the LED will burn up at 4.5V.

See the problem with AA batteries?

This is why you would need a very bright blue LED so you can see it well at 3 mA which is where it would be operating at 3.4V.

When using a battery and resistor the best bet is to use a Li-ion battery which operates from 4V down to 3V. You would need a way to limit the battery voltage and not let the battery discharge below 3V.

---

If you want to use AA batteries you should use a boost regulator.

Connect the batteries in series and use a boost voltage regulator with a 3.3V output.

The other option is to use a multiple output constant current regulator.

---

You could use two [MIC4812](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic4812.pdf)5 output step down CCRs, powered with an LI-ion 18650 battery.

This appears to be the best low cost solution available.

It has a constant current output, up to 20 mA, on each output which is set with a single resistor.  Input voltage can vary from 5.5 V down to almost the V<sub>f</sub> of the LEDs.  Perfect for an Li-ion battery.

[image]